# Are guards to check if a method has been called optimized by Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Consider the following code:

```
public class BasicBuildOrder {
    private List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<GameObject> savedState;

    public void saveState() {
        savedState = new ArrayList<>(gameObjects);
    }

    public void resetToSavedState() {
        if (savedState == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("the state has not been saved");
        }
        gameObjects = savedState;
    }

    public void add(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObjects.add(gameObject);
    }

    public void get(int index) {
        return gameObjects.get(index);
    }

    public void remove(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObjects.remove(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I am implementing a pattern where you can mark a list as saved in some particular state, and later restore that state. I'm aware that the current way of saving/resetting is a bit shady and gives O(n) performance whereas that could be improved by tagging which items have been added, retrieved, removed.

Now an issue I see is that a call to `resetToSavedState()` will be done *before* a call to `saveState()`, hence I need to check for that.

My question is: Is the `if (savedState == null)` check at some point optimized away by Java (either by the compiler, or at runtime) if it knows that `saveState()` has been called and hence `savedState` cannot be `null` anymore?

Additional question, is there a pattern available for this methodA-called-before-methodB relation?

Comment: Unless it can be shown via static analysis that the method is always called, then some kind of runtime information *must* be used.  Thus some kind of check *must* be performed.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to simply check -XX:PrintAssembly output. JIT complier won't compile never taken branch, but it will force deoptimization when the branch would be taken. However, null check should be pretty cheap even without compiler magic.

Comment: How does the code calling this code look? When/How do you call `saveState()` and `resetToSavedState()`? I'm wondering if it's even remotely possible for any static analysis tool to make sure that the method is always called.

Comment: at the very worst, this means an extra fetch from L1 cache... which is nothing. You have a lot more to worry about with all these object costs.

Comment: btw, if you `resetToSavedState` then `add`, the saved state is tempered ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg The idea is to use it for backtracking, so you have a base "BasicBuildOrder", then save state, add something, reset state, repeat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be optimized when compiling Java source to .class-files. It can be optimized in runtime by JIT compiler if both `saveState()` and `resetToSavedState()` are called from the same method and both are inlined there during the JIT compilation (or some deeper call-chain is fully inlined). Inlining is quite possible here as `saveState()` and `resetToSavedState()` are very simple. After that both become parts of the outer method in which after building control-flow graph and value analysis it might become possible to determine that no control paths go into the `if` statement, so such CFG edges will be pruned. However you should not rely that this will occur.

In general you cannot reliably predict the program order just looking at the program code (without actually executing it). However extra null check means almost nothing in terms of performance, so you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the if (savedState == null) check at some point optimized away by Java (either by the compiler, or at runtime) if it knows that saveState() has been called and hence savedState cannot be null anymore?

Neither the JVM, not the JIT optimizes this away completely (in future it might).  However, the CPU can use branch prediction to assume the check will be false and thus has almost no impact. i.e. < 1 ns.

Comment: it's probably a potato CPU if he's worried about such things.

Comment: @bayou.io I doubt it is a worry, more of a curiosity. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a pattern for this "`methodA-called-before-methodB relation`", and you can even encode it into the type-system.

Consider fluid APIs for Builders. That seems to be encapsulating your problem perfectly and even without doing runtime checks:

```
public class BasicBuildOrder {
    protected List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class SavedBuildOrder extends BasicBuildOrder {

        private List<GameObject> savedState;

        private SavedBuildOrder(Collection<GameObject> gameObjects) {
             savedState = new ArrayList<>(gameObjects);
        }

        public void resetToSavedState() {
            gameObjects = savedState;
        }
    }

    public SavedBuildOrder saveState() {
        return new SavedBuildOrder(gameObjects);
    }

    public void add(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObjects.add(gameObject);
    }

    public void get(int index) {
        return gameObjects.get(index);
    }

    public void remove(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObjects.remove(gameObject);
    }
}
```

An alternative to this rather clunky workaround would be something like the [Memento Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

In either case, [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev), [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) and [Filipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249993/filipp) are probably correct anyways:

> However, null check should be pretty cheap even without compiler
>   magic. - Filipp
>
> However extra null check means almost nothing in terms of performance,
>   so you should not worry about it. - Tagir
>
> Unless it can be shown via static analysis that the method is always
>   called, then some kind of runtime information must be used. Thus some
>   kind of check must be performed. - Oliver